# PHP executing commands on software console

Tags: php, console, exec, shell-exec, passthru

I have executed the twinkle-console by using shell_exec and it works perfectly

> unknown@mrunknown-HP-650:~$ twinkle-console
>
> Twinkle 1.10.1, October 7, 2016 Copyright (C) 2005-2015  Michel de Boer and contributors
>
> Users:
>   * profile
>       profile1
>
> Local IP:       255.255.255.255
>
> profile: registering phone...
>
> Twinkle>

now im looking to write & execute command in last line by using this code

```
    <?php
$resault = shell_exec("twinkle-console");
echo $resault."\n";
$resault = system("quit");
echo "OK \n";
```

but it reponse :

> quit:not found

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shell_exec` doesn't support sending input to the running program, and in any case, `system` is the wrong way to do that (it starts a new program with whatever you give it). Instead, use [`proc_open`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) to run the program and get a pipe to its input, and write your commands to that.

Comment: proc_open allows me to execute my commands inside the software, like that
 twinkle>  quit
right ?

Comment: Yes, that's right (and it's exactly what my answer is telling you).

Comment: Thankful to you Mr joseph